# knexjs why mysql doesn't return correct records on selects immediately after insert

Tags: node.js, async.js, knex.js

I insert record by `knexjs` in MySQL but selects after it immediately returns old records. Why? When I set timeout() to delay between the insert and select functions, correct records are returned!

```
function(cb) { //callUser plan
    sd = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    ed = moment(new Date()).add(31, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    space = planDetail.space * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    knex('user_plan')
        .insert({
            'username': userDetail.username,
            'plan_id': planDetail.id,
            'created': knex.raw('NOW()'),
            'start_date': sd,
            'end_date': ed,
            'transaction_id': tran.id,
            'space': space,
            'slot': planDetail.slot
        })
        .asCallback(cb);
},
function(res, cb) {
    logger.log(res);
    return cb(null);
},
function(cb) {
    knex.select('*').from('user_plan').where({
        username: self.username,
    })
    .andWhere('start_date', '<', knex.raw('NOW()'))
    .andWhere('end_date', '>', knex.raw('NOW()'))
    .orderBy('id', 'desc')
    .asCallback(function(err, rows) {
        if(err) return cb(err);

        logger.log(rows);
    });
},
```

Comment: can you please specify, what the execution order of your functions?

Comment: You've indicated in the tags that you're using `async.js` but you've left out which method (parallel, series, etc.) you're using, which could be the issue. Please edit your question to include the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have remote connection to your DB?

In that case maybe your client clock and server clock are in a bit different time. From code I can see that you are creating inserted `sd` and `ed` in client side with `moment()` and then you are comparing selected rows to your DB server time `NOW()`.

You can debug this also by fetching all the rows or just last inserted row (without comparing date) and see that the just inserted row actually is found from DB directly after insert.

Comment: I tested many cases but missed this important case. I should compare dates by >= and <=.  thank you